# How can I get the value of an input tag within a td tag using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to get the value entered into the input tag using jQuery.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh  okay...

Comment: Come on wizards!!!!Shake the magic wand and give it a solution.

Comment: <td><input type="text" /></td>

Comment: $('#tbMain tbody tr').each(function () {
            myObj.EmpId = $(this).find("td").eq(0).html();   This works for getting the value within td but I need to grab the value entered into the input tag

Answer (score 0):

You get it's value by using following code.

```
jQuery('input[name=your_field_machine_name]').val();
```

Comment: Thank you!  Using your answer, the following is what ended up working for what I needed.   $('#tbMain tbody tr').each(function () {

            myObj.FName = $(this).find("td").find("input[name='rank']").val();